# Dynamic Facebook comment counter link

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am wanting to find the href in the series class and then replace the [PAGEURL] with the same link. I also need this to repeat the function for every .details class on the page.

Here is the JavaScript that I am using -

```
$(function() {
  var links = $('.details'),
    matchExp = /\[PAGEURL\]/,
    currentURL = $('.series').attr('href');

  links.each(function() {
    var currentHREF = $(this).attr('href');
    if (currentHREF.match(matchExp)) {
        $(this).attr('href',currentHREF.replace(matchExp,currentURL));
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div class="details">
  <div class="series">
    <a href="MyLink.php">text</a>
  </div>
  <fb:comments-count href=[PAGEURL]></fb:comments-count>
</div>
```

Comment: "There will be 10-15 of these per page" 10-15 of what? Have you tried anything yourself? What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: There will be 10-15 "details" div. The whole page is in php. I thought might help with trying to figure out an answer.

Comment: You haven't really specified what the problem is.

Comment: The script is not working. I used a very similar script for another function and it works great but this one is not. 

I am wanting to replace the [PAGE] in the fb: comments section with "MyLink.php"

Is that more clear?

Comment: Not really - can you define `"not working"` please?  What exactly is not working? Are there any errors?

Comment: no errors. It is not replacing the [PAGE] I am not sure what else to say. How can see if there are any errors?

Comment: You can open the chrome developer tools (F12) and go to the console tab.  Errors will appear in red.

Comment: any error said : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

Comment: Does it say on what line?  In what file?

Comment: its under the currentURL line in the script

Comment: I think it might be this command - `$(.series a).attr('href');`.  It's missing the quotes in the selector.  Change it to - `$('.series a').attr('href');`

Comment: Adding the quotes did take care of the error but did not fix the issue. The [PAGE] sections is not being replaced.

Comment: @Lix here is a link to the page.
http://thatsgrace.org/blog/

Comment: You have to sort out the other erorrs on your page.  You are getting syntax errors, type errors, 404 errors... You'll need to correct those first.

Comment: I have corrected all but one.
Uncaught TypeError: Object /\[PAGE\]/ has no method 'replace'
Not sure what this means though. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: No problem :P  But lets see if we can get it working - why don't you update your post with the code after you corrected it.

Comment: From what i know. Facebook comments, like buttons use Iframes. And you cant access elements inside of a Iframe from another Domain. So, you cant change anything inside the Facebook Tags.

Comment: There is an iframe version of this code but that is not the one that I am using.

Comment: If you could let us know what your trying to actually do mabey we could help more, ie how your mark up is being created etc

Comment: Dominic, it is a static php page.

Comment: Check my updated answer hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need to use regular expressions in this instance.
jQuery provides you with enough tools to get the job done.

Here is how I would accomplish a "search and replace" function on some link placeholders:

Given the following HTML -

```
<div class="details">
  <div class="series"><a href="my_cool_page.php">text</a></div>
  <fb:comments-count href="[PAGEURL]"></fb:comments-count>
</div>

<div class="details">
  <div class="series"><a href="awseome_content.php">text</a></div>
  <fb:comments-count href="[PAGEURL]"></fb:comments-count>
</div>

<div class="details">
  <div class="series"><a href="interesting_stuff.php">text</a></div>
  <fb:comments-count href="[PAGEURL]"></fb:comments-count>
</div>
```

This jQuery would do the trick -

```
$(function(){
    // this grabs all the div elements with the class "details"
    $("div.details").each(function(index,elem){

      // within each details <div>, we look for an <a> element, and
      // we save its href value in currentURL
      var currentURL = $(this).find('div.series > a').attr('href');

      // again within the details <div>, we search for any element who's href
      // property contains [PAGEURL] and replace is with the value
      // we got from the series <a> tag.
      $(this).find('*[href*="[PAGEURL]"]').attr('href',currentURL);
    });
});​
```

The final desired result should look like this -

```
<div class="details">
  <div class="series"><a href="my_cool_page.php">text</a></div>
  <fb:comments-count href="my_cool_page.php"></fb:comments-count>
</div>

<div class="details">
  <div class="series"><a href="awseome_content.php">text</a></div>
  <fb:comments-count href="awseome_content.php"></fb:comments-count>
</div>

<div class="details">
  <div class="series"><a href="interesting_stuff.php">text</a></div>
  <fb:comments-count href="interesting_stuff.php"></fb:comments-count>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WNWtC/)

I made one change to the actual HTML from your question.  The value of the `href` property (and any property for that matter) should always be surrounded with quotes.

`<fb:comments-count href=`**"**`[PAGEURL]`**"**`></fb:comments-count>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQUery, this is pretty straightforward:

```
$('.series').each(function() {
    $(this).next('fb:comments-count').href = this.href;
});
```

Not sure if the jQuery selector 'fb:comment-count' will actually work.  You may want to simply add a class name to that element and use the selector on that class name.

Comment: It won't, because `:` is used for pseudoclasses.

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating this page in PHP, it'll be much easier to just include the URLs server-side. Without knowing more about your script, it would be something like:

```
<?php $url='...'; ?>
<div class="details">
<div class="series"><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">text</a></div>
<fb:comments-count href="<?php echo $url; ?>"></fb:comments-count>
</div>
```

Comment: I did think of this but there will be 10-15 of these details div and each one will have a different url that it will need have in the href.

Does that make sense?

Would it work to use something like ?
    matchExp = /\[PAGEURL\]/,
    currentURL = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: I wouldn't rely on changing the `href` of `<fb:comments-count>` elements client-side.  Changing `href` after the Facebook SDK has already rendered will have no effect.  Instead, just print out the correct URLs from the start (from your server script).

Comment: Is there a way to tell $url to look for the closest href?

$url ='.series href';    ?

Comment: Without seeing how you're generating your page, it's hard to say.

Comment: I am using straight php no DB.

Comment: It's Q&D, but you could just set `$url` before each block.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do will not work as the FB: tags are fired off to Facebook on dom load. This then creates the fb elements in an iframe which you can change.

But If you have multiple links and multiple buttons then you should just hard code them in, but I assume you want one fb button with mutliple links that will modify its url.

If this is the case then your stuck with loading all the buttons on the dom and then showing the one you want

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="series"><a href="MyLink1.php" id="MyLink1">text</a></div>
    <div class="fb MyLink1"><fb:comments-count href=[PAGEURL]"></fb:comments-count></div>

    <div class="series"><a href="MyLink2.php" id="MyLink2">text 2</a></div>
    <div class="fb MyLink2"><fb:comments-count href=[PAGEURL]"></fb:comments-count></div>

    <div class="series"><a href="MyLink3.php" id="MyLink3">text 3</a></div>
    <div class="fb MyLink3"><fb:comments-count href=[PAGEURL]"></fb:comments-count></div>
</div>
```

Then Hide all the fb box's and show the one you want on click

```
$(".fb").hide();
 $(".fb").eq(0).show();

    $(".details . series a").click(function(){
        $(".fb").hide();
        $("."+$(this).attr("id")).show();
    });
```

And then position the fb button some where absolutely some where

```
.fb{
    position:absolut; top:0; left:0;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to create a listings page of multiple pages that have facebook comments on them. I have the comment code all worked out. for the listing page I would like the sample text to also display the comment count for that page. It does not look like it is using an iframe at all. 

Here is a link for the page I am working on. http://thatsgrace.org/blog/

Comment: I do not want 1 button with multiple links. I need multiple buttons with different links for each one. Does that make sense?